# Read result of printf '%q' "$VAR"

Tags: bash, printf

Bash can dump variables as shell-escaped strings:

```
$ X='1 2 te$t'; Y=$' \a\n\t '; printf '%q %q\n' "$X" "$Y" > .data
$ cat .data 
1\ 2\ te\$t $' \a\n\t '
```

Is it possible to recover variables X and Y from file .data? It should be safe, even if .data contains `$(rm -rf /*)`.

I'm searching the way to store records (variables X, Y) in format "one line per record."

**EDIT**

In my task `printf '%q'` may be replaced by urlquote from Python. Solution:

```
$ X='1 2 te$t'; Y=$' \a\n\t ';
$ alias urlquote="python -c'import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.stdin.read())'"
$ alias urlunquote="python -c'import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.stdin.read())'"
$ echo $(echo -n "$X" | urlquote) $(echo -n "$Y" | urlquote) > .data
$ cat .data 
1%202%20te%24t %20%07%0A%09%20
$ while read -r x y; do
>     x=$(echo "$x" | urlunquote)
>     y=$(echo "$y" | urlunquote)
>     printf '%q %q\n' "$x" "$y"
> done < .data 
1\ 2\ te\$t $' \a\n\t '
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer:

printf %q's output, as far as i know, cannot be reconstituted without eval, and eval will always be vulnerable to arbitrary command execution. You'll need to use an encoding not directly supported by bash, e.g. with base64:

```
#!/bin/bash

X='1 2 te$t';
Y=$' \a\n\t ';
echo "$(base64 -w0<<<"$X") $(base64 -w0<<<"$Y")" > .data
cat .data|while read line; do
    X2=$(base64 -d<<<${line%% *})
    Y2=$(base64 -d<<<${line#* })
    printf "%q %q\n" "$X2" "$Y2"
done
```

(original answer removed, see the post history)

Comment: It dangerous on files like `boom $(date)`.

Comment: @sehe - not a typo, $(<file) is shorthand for $(cat file), and <(cmd) is something else... what's $<(.data)?

Comment: @je4d: ah right, my mix up was insane, i'd never seen 'implicit cat' by 'naked input redirection' before. +1

Comment: @dmage - apologies, you're entirely right. AFAIK printf %q is the only way to perfectly store/restore a variable using pure bash, and you have no option but to use eval to restore it. Except in some older versions where array decls worked without the eval due to a bug, and they may be vulnerable anyway.

You'll have to resort to using two base64-encoded strings per line in your file and using an external app to convert

Comment: A robust approach, but it's worth noting that `base64` is not a standard utility and that the `-w` option is GNU-specific (BSD `base64` never wraps lines), and BSD `base64` uses `-D` rather than (`-d`) for decoding.
Also, I suggest not using the `while` loop in a _subshell_, because the point of reading from the file is to create variables for later use. Use `while … done < .data` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I'd go about it like so

```
X='1 2 te$t'
Y=$' \a\n\t '

{ 
     printf "X=%q" "$X"
     printf "Y=%q" "$Y"
} > .data
```

Then to restore:

```
source .data
```

**EDIT**

Why don't you just

```
(echo "$X"; echo "$Y") > .data
readarray ENVVARS < .data

X="${ENVVARS[0]}"
Y="${ENVVARS[1]}"
```

Note that `readarray` requires bash 4+. You could approximate the same with `read`

Comment: Yes, but what if somebody replace .data with `rm -rf /`? I'm looking for simple bash-friendly storage. It should never destroy my system.

Comment: @dmage: proposed a safer approach

Comment: @dmage: I know that. What's your point? If you require all that, why don't you mention it in your post? We're wasting time here

Comment: Y=$' \a\n\t '... I need all symbols for filenames (all except \0). I want to store pairs <filename> <comment> in text file (i.e. \0 should not be delimiter). Maybe bash wrong language for this task...

Comment: @dmage: it would be appreciated if you could state such goals/requirements in the question next time :) Now, since you require all symbols for filenames, you're stuck: firstly `\0` MUST be the delimiter (nothing else is POSIX-ly correct) and secondly you can't have `records (variables X, Y) in format "one line per record."` because filenames are allowed as many newline characters as they think is right. Saly I'm not aware of ways to make readarray accept \0 delimited 'lines' so AFAICT you're gonna need a real programming language (perl, python, ruby, c etc)

Comment: It possible to solve this using not human-friendly encoding: `echo $(echo "$X" | base64 -w0) $(echo "$Y" | base64 -w0)`. Encoding via `printf %q` much more friendly, but I have no idea how to read this. Oh, thanks! I can use `python -c'import urllib, sys; print urllib.quote(sys.stdin.read())'` as encoder!! :)

Comment: @sehe To be pedantic, you could use / as your delimiter if it was strictly file names, and not paths, that you wanted to store :-)

If you really want to get a zero-delimited file into bash variables, you could do it via arrays and eval, by creating known-safe input to eval with something like: xargs -0 -n2   bash -c 'printf "%q %q\n" "$0" "$1"'